# Cannot close Microsoft Word document

Tags: macos, ms-office

I am using Microsoft Word for Mac on my MacBook Pro OS X (Yosemite). I tried closing a Word document but clicking on the red button made it turn gray and nothing happened. I can minimize the Word document, but can't move it to trash nor save the document.

Comment: moving to trash is not a word operation is it? What happens if you quit Word?

Comment: MS is usually good in telling you why. So look for a message (probably hidden behind other windows).

Comment: are you using 365 or 2011?

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to Quit Word from the drop down menu, but I found that when I clicked the Apple icon in the upper left corner, I could click on Force Quit and that worked!

Answer (score 0):

In Mac MSWord with the document open and the three buttons x + - not showing
you seem to have no facility to close the document without quitting Mac MSWord.

You can go to the File drop down menu and select Close file. The active document closes.

Mac MSWord remains open, so you can continue work on other documents. It is my experience that not all Mac MSWord documents I am working in present without the no x + - buttons phenomenon
. So there seems some underlying issue ...

When the buttons are visible the File dropdown menu does not yield this Close file option.

Answer (score -2):

Just hit escape and file will shrink, and options to close, minimize reappear

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We like answers to be more than just a single line.  Ideally, you want to explain why your answer is *right."  It also helps to provide links, citations, and/or screen shots.  Please review our help section [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers to questions

Answer (score -2):

Just hit " command q" and it will close all windows.